# Azure function in Isolated process, how to create CloudBlobContainer from [BlobInput]

Tags: azure-functions, hosting

I am migrating Azure functions "inprocess" hosting to "isolated" hosting.

but I want to write to a blob container, I am not able to see any documentation for write  to a blob container.

A sample code shown below. I am getting blob as string (Documentation from microsoft ), how can I convert that to CloudBlobContainer for adding new files from eventhub.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace sample
{
    public class SampleFunctionApp
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public SampleFunctionApp(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SampleFunctionApp>();
        }

        [Function("SampleFunctionApp")]
        public void Run([EventHubTrigger("eventhubname", Connection = "conn-string")] string[] input,
        [BlobInput("path",Connection = "StateStorageConnectionString")] string myBlob,
        FunctionContext context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"First Event Hubs triggered message: {input[0]}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to write the event hub message to a blob you need a blob output binding, not a blob input binding.

Comment: in output binding also I am not able to do this.
`var errorBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("errors/" + this.GetType().Name + "/" + eventData.PartitionKey + " - " + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);`
How to generate CloudBlobContainer from output binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given in this MS Doc, Isolated Process doesn't support the `CloudBlockBlob` Class bindings:

[image]

AFAIK, the `BlobContainerClient` Class is used for the .NET Isolated Process for accessing the blobs using the NuGet Package `Azure.Storage.Blobs

[image]

Refer to the MS Doc [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide) & [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-dotnet&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet-isolated) for more information on supporting Storage account container classes for dotnet-isolated process.

Comment: Hey, do you know by any chance to use CloudBlobContainer outputContainer in isolated model?

Comment: Why do you paste images and not text?