# Migrating in-proc Azure function to isolated function - How to use generic Binder

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated

I have a working .NET6 in-proc Azure Function. I'm in the process of converting it to an isolated worker process (out-of-proc) .net7 function.
I have a HttpTrigger function that should get a file from the blob-storage. Since the blob-storage is case-sensitive and all files are saved in upper-case, I need to make the input upper-case as well.
With the in-proc function, I did that by injecting  `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.IBinder binder` and then use `binder.BindAsync<byte[]>(new Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.BlobAttribute($"%BlobContainerName%/{fooUpper}", FileAccess.Read)`

This is the .net6 in-proc function:

```cs
[Function(nameof(GetFile))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "bar/{foo}")] HttpRequest req,
    Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.IBinder binder, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext context, string foo)
{
    // The file name is always upper-case:
    var fooUpper = foo.ToUpperInvariant();
    var blobStream = await binder.BindAsync<byte[]>(
            new Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.BlobAttribute($"%BlobContainerName%/{fooUpper}", FileAccess.Read),
            req.FunctionContext.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return await ExecuteAsync(fooUpper, context.FunctionDirectory, blobStream,
                req.FunctionContext.CancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Of course, I tried migrating this function to a .net7 isolated function by replacing `HttpRequest req` with `HttpRequestData req` and it compiles but when I run it `binder` is always `null`.

What is the isolated function version of my function?

- Do I need to create a custom attribute?
- Or create some middleware that makes the URL upper-case?
- Or should I create a service that I register during start-up and use with DI in the function class?

Please advice.

Comment: you cannot create a file with upper case in blob stroage

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We do have all our files as upper-case in the blob storage. But that is not the issue. I need to know how to get access to the blob storage, so I can get the file myself. BolbContainerClient is no longer working in isolated mode, IBinder is not working. Middleware doesn't help. I need to know what is working.

Answer (score 1):

Check if my below findings helpful to fix your issue:

> BlobContainerClient is no longer working in isolated mode

AFAIK, `BlobContainerClient` should work with the .NET Isolated Process Version 7 in Azure Functions using `Azure.Storage.Blobs` NuGet Package as shown in this SO Answer #[75015570](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75015570/azure-function-in-isolated-process-how-to-create-cloudblobcontainer-from-blobi) by the user @*HariKrishna* and [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-dotnet&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet-isolated).

[image]

If you use the NuGet Package `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, you can initialize the `BlobContainerClient` class-objects which is compatible in .NET Isolated Process and for working with the Blob Container Objects, you have to initialize the BlobServiceClient for Connecting to Storage Account and getting access to the Blob Container.

```cs
public HttpResponseData Run([Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "bar/{foo}")] HttpRequestData req,
            BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient, IBinder binder, ExecutionContext executionContext)
```

Here is the GitHub [Article](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp.md#binding-at-runtime) on Azure Functions .NET Isolated Process of using the **Ibinder** input parameter for data binding and there are some examples provided in the same article for working in the context of **Ibinder** and **StorageAccountAttribute** such as `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.BlobAttribute`.